# Something goes wrong with default brush setting in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

I have just installed my new Graphic tablet and a strange behavior appears to me in Illustrator CS6.

The old day I used to pick my brush or any drawing tool and choose my stroke weight and the brush definition then I start drawing peacefully.

Here I set the brush weight to 2cm and a basic brush profile:

[image]

Now I couldn't do that. Every time I pick any drawing tool and set the stroke weight and brush definition, the moment I start to draw those settings reset their values like those appearing in the following screen capture. Just as if there is a default locked value and I couldn't change whatever it did.

Here Illustrator reset my above setting and changed it to 0.0353 cm and set the brush profile to 3 pt round.

[image]

I reset my workspace and even I detached my graphic tablet and nothing happens.

Do you have any idea what's going on and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Basic" is *not* a brush**.

In fact, it actually means "remove all brush strokes" or "reduce to *basic* path". Adobe put it in a stupid, unintuitive, place. But that's what it's there for. If you *actually want* a brush stroke, then "Basic" is not a correct option. Note, when using the Brush Tool, "Basic" will be ignored because with the Brush tool, a brush stroke *must* be applied. So, generally the first *actual* brush is used - which is most commonly a small calligraphic brush. If you want to draw freeform and create "basic" paths, then use the Pencil Tool, not the Brush Tool.

If you want settings to continue as you draw, ensure "New Art has Basic Appearance" is **not** checked in the **Appearance Panel Menu.**

[image]

If that item is checked, each *new* path will be reset to the default appearance.

Comment: nice tip, Thank you. by the way .. why I could apply a specific brush profile to the blob brush and now I couldn't ?

Comment: The blob brush will only accept calligraphic brush profiles. All other brush types don't work with the blob brush.